# What is the force of asteroids that hit Mars?

Tags: mars, asteroid

Below is a link to an article I was reading (Keeping in mind it was difficult for me to find any other articles of the kind) that talks about how often asteroids hit Mars. 
Unfortunately, it is very vague in its information, both on the size of the asteroids and the mass (Including the composition of the asteroids)

What exactly would be the force (In g's or N) of an asteroid hitting the surface of Mars, keeping in mind that Mars has a lower gravitational force than Earth and a very weak atmosphere? It would be appreciated if anyone could provide information on even just the mass of the asteroids that commonly hit the surface of the planet.

Thanks!

https://www.space.com/21198-mars-asteroid-strikes-common.html

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without specifying the exact composition of the surface they hit (sand, rock...) and the exact material, structure and shape of the asteroid. You might ask for the speed at impact instead.

Comment: but the speed will be dependant on the terminal velocity, which will depend on the composition...

Comment: @OrganicMarble: also varying with location on the asteroid and impact point, both of which are going to change shape (and physical state) drastically as a result of those forces. And _g_ s are units of acceleration, not force. Impact velocity and energy are more useful pieces of information.

Comment: The Purdue [Impact Earth](https://www.purdue.edu/impactearth/) site's [documentation](https://www.purdue.edu/impactearth/Content/pdf/Documentation.pdf) includes formulae for estimating some of these quantities. The formulae for the energy and atmospheric entry will likely be OK with modifications for the scale height and density of the Martian atmosphere. The ones for crater dimensions, which are scaled from small-scale hypervelocity experiments and nuclear explosions on Earth, are not likely to apply exactly.